# I don't understand why this program is not working. Polymorphism

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, polymorphism, overriding

I recently started programming and I am busy with inheritance, polymorphism and overriding. Now I just made this program and for some reason it doesn't work.
The compiler underlines " = new Arraylist(); but I do not know why.

The code is as following:

Super class: Person

```
public class Person {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public void print() {
    System.out.println("\t" + firstName + " " + lastName);
}
}
```

Subclass: Teacher

```
public class Teacher extends Person {
public Teacher(String firstName, String lastName) {
    super(firstName, lastName);
}

public void print() {
    System.out.println("Professor Details: ");
    super.print();
}

}
```

Subclass Student:

```
public class Student extends Person {
private int graduationYear;
private double gpa;

public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int graduationYear, double gpa) {
    super(firstName, lastName);
    this.graduationYear = graduationYear;
    this.gpa = gpa;
}

public void print() {
    System.out.println("Student Details: ");
    super.print();
    System.out.println("\t" + graduationYear);
    System.out.println("\t" + gpa);
}
}
```

Main class: (Where I initialize the arraylist, it doesn't work for some reason. (Fat is an error in the compiler: Arraylist persons = new **Arraylist**();

```
public class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Person> persons = new Arraylist();
    persons.add(new Student("Sam", "Young", 2017, 3.6));
    persons.add(new Student("Dan", "Sella", 2012, 2.5));
    persons.add(new Student("Kevin", "Cane", 2016, 2.7));

    for(Person person : persons) {
        person.print();
    }
}

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Java is case-sensitive. `ArrayList` != `Arraylist`. You also want to avoid using the raw type, but that's a slightly separate issue.

Answer (score 5):

`ArrayList` is initialized like this:

```
ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
```

Or, if you're using version below Java SE 7:

```
ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

Notice the `<>` (Diamond) and ArrayList.

Comment: Ahhh.. I am so messy. I'm sorry. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should create `ArrayList` Object like below code:

```
ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

in above you have missing to add `<Person>` in  object creation .

Comment: Thanks. I am very messy. :(

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
ArrayList<Person> persons = new Arraylist();
```

**ArrayList** persons = new **Arraylist**();
*You have case error here*

try

```
ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

if you still have error than may be upgrade your java compiler level to 1.5 or greater